# Problem with pip, cant install modules from cmd

Tags: python, opencv

I just get a syntax error. I've tried these commands:

```
pip install opencv-python 
pip3 install opencv-python 
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

All of these just give me a syntax error.

Trying to install opencv for some webcams, going to be messing with raspberry later.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, are you running these commands inside Python? If so, they should not be and you should first run exit() to make sure your command terminal doesn't have Python running.

Comment: try installing it in your python path 
Ex:cd c:\users\youruser\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages and then pip install opencv-python

Comment: First you have to run 
pip install --upgrade pip
because 19.3 is the minimum supported version

Comment: or use the default version: pip install opencv-contrib-python

Comment: That was it I was running python while doing these commands thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you have just to type `py -m pip install opencv-python`.

If you are on a Linux distribution you should firstly install `python-pip` or `python3-pip` (via your package manager) and then type:

- `pip (or pip3) install opencv-python` (if you want to install it locally).
- `sudo pip (or pip3) install opencv-python` (if you want to install it globally).

You can find more information [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/).

Comment: Thats the thing is when I type py -m pip install opencv-python or any other command that usually works it gives me a syntax error,

Comment: what's your current environment? Maybe you deleted some system paths by mistake.